# Removing a list of lists from another

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to remove elements if it appears in a and b (not all occurrences of it)

```
a = [[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0] , [2.0, 3.0]]
b = [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0] , [3.0, 4.0]]
```

Expected output

```
c = [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

If a point appears twice in a and twice in b then the output should contain the point twice

```
a = [[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0] , [2.0, 3.0]]
b = [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0] , [3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0]]
```

Expected output

```
c = [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0]]
```

I have tried

```
 first_set = set(map(tuple, a))
 secnd_set = set(map(tuple, b))

 first_set.symmetric_difference(secnd_set)
```

But this takes into account elements within a or b themselves.

Edited: a second example for clarification

Comment: Can you post what you tried so far? You should have a look at `=` and list comprehensions.

Comment: if you converted all of them to tuples with `a = list(map(tuple, a))` etc. then you'd just do `c = set(a) | set(b)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you first convert each pair to a tuple with something like this:

```
a = [tuple(item) for item in a]
b = [tuple(item) for item in b]
```

then you can simply take the set `union` between the two:

```
c = set(a).union(b)
```

This will give you a set with one of each pair that appears at least once in either or both collections:

```
>>> c
{(1.0, 2.0), (3.0, 4.0), (2.0, 3.0), (1.0, 4.0)}
```

If you want this behaviour keeping multiples then simply substitute [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for `set`, then you can get them all back in one collection with [`.elements()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.elements)

```
from collections import Counter
a = [[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0] , [2.0, 3.0]]
b = [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0] , [3.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0]]
a1 = Counter(map(tuple,a))
b1 = Counter(map(tuple,a))
c = a1 | b1

>>> c
Counter({(2.0, 3.0): 2, (1.0, 2.0): 1, (1.0, 4.0): 1, (3.0, 4.0): 1})
>>> list(c.elements())
[(2.0, 3.0), (2.0, 3.0), (1.0, 2.0), (1.0, 4.0), (3.0, 4.0)]
```

Comment: They want the symmetric difference, not the union, so `set(a)  ^ set(b)` if you want to stick with those operators. Although the example output seems to be mistaken, so it's ambiguous.

Comment: the expected output shows the union - one of every unique element that appears collectively in both collections.  The OP shows that they tried `symmetric_difference` and it didn't work, I assume because it's the union they want.

Comment: The output should contain elements that appear in both a and b. It should also add repetitions into the output. Please check the edit.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanAlMahmoud sorry I didn't initially see your edit, I have updated the post with info about `Counter`, I hope it now solves your issue

Answer (score 1):

This solution may not be efficient, but may give the result:

```
a = [[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0] , [2.0, 3.0]]
b = [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0] , [3.0, 4.0]]
c = []

for item in a:
    if item not in c:
        c.append(item)

for item in b:        
    if item not in c:
        c.append(item)

print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 4.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use itertools groupby

```
a = [[2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0] , [2.0, 3.0]]
b = [[1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0] , [3.0, 4.0]]

import itertools
c = [k for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(a+b))]

will result in

[[1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 4.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0]]
```